# `nowidow.sty` not found

Tags: packages, installing

I've been working on this for the last three hours and found no clue. This morning I found the blog [Certificates with LaTeX](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/certificates-with-latex/) and downloaded the tex file [certificate.tex](https://github.com/harishkumarholla/Certificate/blob/master/certificate.tex). When I compile this in my emacs I run into the following error report:

> ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `nowidow.sty' not found

I followed the instruction on this post:

[Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

and put the `nowidow.sty` into the directory: `/usr/local/share/texmf/nowidow`

But the error report still pops up.  Did I put the file in the wrong directory or am I missing other important steps? Could anyone help me? My system is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: you will need to run texhash to rebuild the search database

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a TeX directory structure below `.../texmf/`. In your case the `.sty` file should go into

```
/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/nowidow/nowidow.sty
```

The subdirectory `tex` means "TeX files" and the subdirectory `latex` stands for the TeX format "LaTeX" (format file `latex`). Documentation: [A Directory Structure for TeX files](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tds/tds.pdf).

Usually you also need to refresh the file name database for `TEXMFLOCAL` by running `texhash` or `mktexlsr` (as root because of `/usr`).